# Troubleshooting Warning: 'could not load hiredis extension' when Installing SQL Adapter and Tiny_tds Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

To connect my app and SQL server, I am trying to install sql adapter and tiny_ids gem which I can use for the connectivity purpose. However during the installation of______________, I am getting below warning and installation doesn't happen.
WARNING: could not load hiredis extension, using (slower) pure Ruby implementation. C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:17:in require': cannot load such file -- tiny_tds/tiny_tds (LoadError) from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:17:in require' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/tiny_tds-0.7.0-x64-mingw32/lib/tiny_tds.rb:23:in rescue in ' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/tiny_tds-0.7.0-x64-mingw32/lib/tiny_tds.rb:22:in ' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in require' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in require' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:60:in block (2 levels) in require' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in each' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in block in require' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:44:in each' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:44:in require' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler.rb:187:in require' from C:/Azure/RiskNet/config/application.rb:13:in ' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in require' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in require' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.3/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:22:in require_application!' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.3/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:14:in require_application_and_environment!' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.3/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:101:in perform' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in run' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in invoke_command' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor.rb:392:in dispatch' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.3/lib/rails/command/base.rb:87:in perform' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.3/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in invoke' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in ' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in require' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in require' from bin/rails:4:in ' C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:17:in require': cannot load such file -- tiny_tds/3.0/tiny_tds (LoadError) from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:17:in require' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/tiny_tds-0.7.0-x64-mingw32/lib/tiny_tds.rb:21:in ' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in require' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in require' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:60:in block (2 levels) in require' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in each' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in block in require' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:44:in each' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:44:in require' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler.rb:187:in require' from C:/Azure/RiskNet/config/application.rb:13:in ' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in require' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in require' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.3/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:22:in require_application!' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.3/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:14:in require_application_and_environment!' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.3/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:101:in perform' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in run' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in invoke_command' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor.rb:392:in dispatch' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.3/lib/rails/command/base.rb:87:in perform' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.3/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in invoke' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in ' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in require' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in require' from bin/rails:4:in `'

I Tried tiny_tds and activerecord-sqlserver-adapter gem to connect vm server to my app on local.
I am working on Ruby on Rails application which has to connect to MS SQL Server. Currently I am running my application and SQL server both on the same development machine.  Here is the more details:
Ruby Version:: 3.0.4
Rails Version: 7.0.4
gem 'tiny_tds', '~>2.0.0'
gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter'

Comment: Did you install those gems?

Comment: Yes when i am trying to install tiny_tds gem getting this error